# What is the small microphone icon floating on top of the screen in macOS and how do I turn it off?

Tags: macos, catalina, voice-dictation

I'm not sure how I did this, but I now have this floating over everything:

> [image]

I'm curious what it is, and how I can turn it off.
I'm currently running macOS Catalina.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's the dictation feature of macOS -- it allows you to speak to the computer and have the spoken words translated into text input and actions. To turn it off go to: `System Preferences > Keyboard` and press the `Dictation` tab:

[image: Dictation System Preferences]

You'll see an option to disable it from there.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203085

Comment: I had the same problem but for me it wasn't dictation, it was VoiceOver was turned on in the System Preferences > Accessibility > VoiceOver. It used the same icon as dictation.

Comment: In my case this was not it. If dictation is not enabled, it could be, as in my case, Voice control. This option can be disabled through System Preferences > Accessibility > Voice Control.

Answer (score 71):

This microphone floating on your screen IS NOT the dictation feature. It is the Voice Control.

- Go to **System Preferences** > **Accessibility**
- Scroll down until you see "**Voice Control**"
- **Disable** Voice Control.

Comment: Dictation uses a very similar microphone icon so it really could be either one is turned on for that to show up on your display.

Comment: I have turned off this option but this microphone is still floating and using 80% cpu.
How to turn this off forever?

Comment: IT IS fucking brilliant whatever it is, makes me feel like I am shooting the shit with HAL! Don't screw me, I know I am supposed to be informative.

Comment: This answer works. Note that 'Voice Control' should not be confused with the 'VoiceOver' accessibility settings. Initially I typed 'voice...' and arrived at the wrong setting.